# Errors running 'composer update' with ONGR ES-Bundle

Tags: elasticsearch, ongr

i'm running the ONGR ElasticSearchBundle in my Symfony Project(prexously i user only the ES-PHP Client). I'll search an existing Index with Company Names and Descriptions, the index Name is companies. It looks this way:

```
"mappings": {
        "_doc": {
            "properties": {
                "id": {"type": "long"},
                "entityid": {"type": "long"},
                "entityname": {"type": "keyword"},
                "name": {"type": "text"},
                "street": {"type": "text"},
                "city": {"type": "text"},
                "zip": {"type": "long"},
                "ziptext": {"type": "keyword"},
                "regionisocode": {"type": "keyword"},
                "desc": {"type": "text"},
                "branch": {"type": "text"},
                "branchid": {"type": "long"},
                "foundingyear": {"type": "date"}

            }
        }
    }
```

The Document Class looks this way:

```
/**
 * Company
 *
 * @ES\Document()
 */
class Company
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ES\Property(type="long", options={"index"="not_analyzed"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ES\Property(type="long", options={"index"="not_analyzed"})
     */
    private $entityid;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ES\Property(type="keyword", options={"index"="not_analyzed"})
     */
    private $entityname;
...
```

When i change the Annotation to:

```
/**
 * Company
 *
 * @ES\Document(type="_doc")
 */
```

then The Search is running fine but then i can't execute any composer commands because i get this Error:
`[RuntimeException]An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundExcepton] The service "company_search_service" has a dependency on a non-existent service "es.manager.default.company".`
I found an Issue in the Bundle on [GitHub](https://github.com/ongr-io/demo.ongr.io/issues/19) but it's more than four years a go and its closed.

Without the `@ES\Document(type="_doc")` Annotation i can't acces the index. Maybe someone has a suggestion?
Thank you in advance

I'm using Symfony 2.8 and ONGR/Elastic Bundle 5.2.4

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if its still relevant, but the service that is failing is a repository service for your document. It is failing because you are probably requireing it somewhere.
The repository service name is made dynamically by appending the manager service name (`es.manager.default`) with the type name (by default a lowercased document class name, in your case -  `company`), hence - `es.manager.default.company`. When you add a different type name (`_doc` in this case) your repository name changes to, I presume, `es.manager.default._doc`. 
You could check this and change your service requirements but I would honestly discourage using `_doc` as type name.